# Storing 0.5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using a decimal (I have tried variations of it) 0.5 is always converted to 5.

I can store 1.5, etc, no problem... Just curious on how I need to set up my data type to correctly store a '0.5' number.

Thanks

EDIT:

The current data type is Decimal (3,1). I have tried float as well.

I simply retreive the number through $_POST from a Form text box which is restricted to numbers only through Java. I never considered that maybe the browser is simply sending it as a 5, I don't know.

EDIT 2: I have confirmed through echo that the 0.5 is sent fine, it's once it gets into the database that it becomes 5

Comment: Can you show us your datatype for that column?

Comment: what is your current data type? already tried float?

Comment: And provide the expression for storing the data as well.

Comment: Sorry, let me update my post with the appropriate info. 2 minutes. Thanks

Comment: Please give a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of the code that's causing this problem.  Also, consider turning on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html) to see what statement MySQL is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, I might get voted down for this, but I've always had success (as a sort of hack) in storing values like this as a VARCHAR and then using  [format()](https://www.php.net/number_format) function in PHP when I need to make calculations.  MySQL still seems to parse it well enough for SQL functions as well.  Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: I will have to do it this way if there isn't a more logical way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Parse it, yes.  But *efficiently* perform lookups & calculations on it when required?  No.  Horrible, horrible, answer.  Don't do this!

Comment: I know it wouldn't be efficient for lookups at all, but this data is really just stored and displayed later... Not related to the lookups, it's on the last resort table

Comment: @eggyal - For calculations and large-scale indexing, you're totally right.  That's why I posted with trepidation.  

Conversely, efficiency seems to be judged based on use-case and business rules.  The situation didn't seem to call for anything more than a simple solution so I thought I'd just point this out.  Try to be a bit more open-minded :)

from a developer's POV, sometimes the simplest way is indeed the most efficient :)

Comment: Sadly, I've far too often seen the unintended consequences of developers taking the "simplest way" merely to avoid fixing/understanding an issue.

Comment: @eggyal - I do see your point, and it is a prudent one to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I used a decimal value in a database with various inputs:

I have tried to recreate you issue, but I get the following:

```
mysql> create table test(myDec decimal(2,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(0.5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> insert into test values(.5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+-------+
| myDec |
+-------+
|  0.50 |
|  0.50 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Given your edit, I think that you might be getting values from international visitors, where the decimal point might be formatted using a comma instead of a dot?

```
mysql> insert into test values('0,5');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+-------+
| myDec |
+-------+
|  0.50 |
|  0.50 |
|  0.00 |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I also tried, and got correct values. Reason may be as suggested by Fluffeh. It is general European standard, to have "," as decimals. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,362125,362125